# Table numbering by section with letters

Tags: tables, captions

I have a 2 part table that I wish to label as "a" and "b", that also includes the section number and the table number within the section (e.g., "Table 4.1a" and Table "4.1b").

I use the basic approach to produce a caption which includes the section number (the `\counterwithin{table}{section}` command). However, when I try to integrate a subcaption, I can only produce "Table 1a" and "Table 1b", which does not include the section number.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}a}
\caption{First caption}\label{first}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}b}
\caption{Second caption}\label{second}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

How can I integrate the `\counterwithin{table}{section}` command so that section numbers are also included?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcounter{mysubtable}
\newcommand\modcounter{%
  \refstepcounter{mysubtable}%
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}\alph{mysubtable}}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}
Some cross-references to tables~\ref{first} and~\ref{second}.

\begin{table}
\modcounter
\caption{First caption}
\label{first}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\addtocounter{table}{-1}
\modcounter
\caption{Second caption}
\label{second}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Remarks

- A new counter `mysubtable` was defined.
- A helping command `\modcounter` was also defined to (ref)step the `mysubtable` counter and to redefine `\thetable` to preppend the section counter.
- To restart the counter, add

  ```
  \setcounter{mysubtable}{0}
  ```

  at the appropriate location.

Comment: Works great, but unfortunately does not "reset with a new table number; continues at the next letter. For example, Table 1.1a and Table 1.1b will be followed by Table1.2c and Table 1.2d

Comment: Update: By redefining the command before each table, you can get the letters to restart at a: e.g., \newcounter{mysubtable2}
\renewcommand\modcounter{%
  \refstepcounter{mysubtable2}%
  \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection.\arabic{table}\alph{mysubtable2}}%
}

Comment: @Dan This can be done in a simpler way. When I get home I'll update my answer.

Comment: Can this be modified to work for figures?